# how do i make sure the user tweeted or not [ i mean tweeted not clicked on a tweet button ]?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, sttwitterapi

I'm gonna give a user discount when he tweeted through my website but I want to make sure that the user actually tweeted, not just clicked on a tweet button.
I have tried `

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
   twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
      console.log(event);
   });
});
```

but this detects only that the user clicked on a tweet button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't get the scenario but you can do a lot of options to assure he tweets or not:

- if user signed in Twitter , then you can  use twitter api and check whether this tweet is published or not using this api : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets
- make the place he tweets in (form) to post the tweet and then you could track whether he tweets or not using this api : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update